# Fabric/Crashlytics on Android - How to have two different crashlytics projects with the same package name?

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I am developing an Android application and I want to have two different projects in Crashlytics / Fabric (debug and release).

I know that this is possible by having two different package names, but in my case, the package name of these two build types have to be the same.

Is there any possibility to have two crashlytics projects with the same package name?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hello I also had same questions months ago and I solved it myself. Hope my answer will help you.

You need 2 organizations with different `crashlyticsApiKey` for each of your project on fabric.

Then on your `build.gradle` file you will define `manifestPlaceHolders`

```
debug {
        manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsApiKey: 'your_api_key_for_debug_project_here']
    }

release {
        manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsApiKey: 'your_api_key_for_release_project_here']
    }
```

Then you will put this variable on meta-data at your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="${crashlyticsApiKey}" />
```

That's all, now build your project both for relase and debug, you will see your app will registered for 2 different fabric account with same package nam

Comment: How can I find these api keys?

Comment: In your fabric dashboard you can find your api keys for each of your project

Comment: I can only see the api key for my organisation... I looked for other projects in my organisation and they all refer to the same api key in the manifest file. How did you manage to have different api keys for each project?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the mention, you need to create 2 organistaion, and use apikeys from them.

Comment: There is also an `apiSecret` key that is kept at `fabric.properties` how to handle this in case of 2 different organizations? I also have 2 of these :(

Answer (score 11):

There is also an option where you do not need to create multiple organizations. You can use the [Fabric.Builder](https://docs.fabric.io/javadocs/fabric/1.3.10/index.html) with `appIdentifier(java.lang.String appIdentifier)`.

The only thing to do is replace the Crashlytics initialization from the documentation

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

with something like this:

```
final String trackingId = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".tv";
Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this).kits(new Crashlytics()).appIdentifier(trackingId).build();
Fabric.with(fabric);
```

The second snippet uses projects `APPLICATION_ID` (package name) and adds a ".tv" to it.

NOTE: when you track your crashes this way, Crashlytics does not create the project by itself. It is important to have the project created manually (or having the project already created from another App with the same package name).

Comment: Thanks for the NOTE! That's the piece I was missing, resolved all my issues!