# Use two different accounts with Fabric

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-fabric

I have an application with some separated modules.
In addition, I want to use a different fabric users (api keys) for each module.
When I try to register another module with the fabric key in the manifest, like this:

```
<meta-data
   android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
   android:value="My_Key" />
```

I get an error of duplicated apikey.
Is there any option to implement this?

Comment: @MohammedAtif - not exactly . he can use the replace attribute for ignoring the error, but still can't use 2 fabric accounts at the same time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36887058/fabric-crashlytics-on-android-how-to-have-two-different-crashlytics-projects-w